# Java - How do I make a String array with values?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I know how to make an empty array, but how do I make a `String` array with values from the start?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
String[] myStrings = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

or in expression

```
functionCall(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
```

or

```
String myStrings[];
myStrings = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

Comment: Or `String[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };`, since the OP has asked specifically about Strings.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I want to make an array with strings.

Comment: Yes, I see the tag now. Strings not mentioned in the question, though. Thanks for update.

Comment: for completness, you should also add `return new String[] {"one", "two"};`

Answer (score 6):

By using the array initializer list syntax, ie:

```
String myArray[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to create an array with String apart from

```
String[] strings =  { "abc", "def", "hij", "xyz" };
```

is to use split.  I find this more readable if there are lots of Strings.

```
String[] strings =  "abc,def,hij,xyz".split(",");
```

or the following is good if you are parsing lines of strings from another source.

```
String[] strings =  ("abc\n" +
                     "def\n" +
                     "hij\n" +
                     "xyz").split("\n");
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is with [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)), or [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)):

```
String[] v = new String[1000];
Arrays.setAll(v, i -> Integer.toString(i * 30));
//v => ["0", "30", "60", "90"... ]

Arrays.fill(v, "initial value");
//v => ["initial value", "initial value"... ]
```

This is more usefull for initializing (possibly large) arrays where you can compute each element from its index.

Answer (score 2):

You want to initialize an array. (For more info - [Tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)l)

```
int []ar={11,22,33};

String []stringAr={"One","Two","Three"};
```

From the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html)

The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both, as in this example:

```
byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
```

This declaration is equivalent to:

```
byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the tutorial but he did ask about Strings, in a roundabout sort of way (tagged it with "string").

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone put the `[]` right at the start of the variable name, that looks funny.